# Why wont chrome fire this mouseover event properly?

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple web page with a block of javascript that I am trying to view locally.
The code is hosted on a local apache server (Im not browsing files directly from the filesystem).
e.g. I view the code with a local URL like

```
http://localhost/website_projects/app/
```

HTML

```
<a href="" id="whats-this-category"><sub>Whats this?</sub></a>
```

Javascript

```
var el = document.getElementById('whats-this-category');
el.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
    alert('event fired');
});
```

[fiddle of this code](https://jsfiddle.net/pf2zxfb3/)

This code runs properly on the fiddle (even when viewing with chrome) it runs properly locally when viewed with firefox, but when viewing locally with chrome - the mouseover event only fires when the link is *clicked* - not when mouseover.
Im aware there is or was a bug in chrome dev tools, where mouseover wont work if you have the dev tools window open or when you try to run javascript directly from files on the filesystem chrome wont work either.
Wont wont chrome run this mouseover event properly?

Comment: Works for me, and I'm on chrome.

Comment: yes if I browse the code on the fiddle it works for me too, but the same code - when I view it locally - doesnt work on chrome, Im wondering if there is some dev tools setting causing the issue

Comment: Are you applying any css that could be causing the element to collapse, and is this the actual javascript you're attempting locally?

Comment: Have you checked the developer console for errors? That sounds suspiciously like Javascript which stopped executing before adding the listener.

Comment: What's the point of using `<sub>` alone without any surrounding text??!!

Comment: Do you have some Chrome settings/extensions enabled for your local domain for simulating a mobile browser? I would imagine click for `mouseover` would be a behavior for that.

Comment: @Jacob - no there doesnt seem to be any mobile specific features turned on - and emulation is disabled

Comment: @patstuart console is showing no errors

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, with window.onload and CDATA, that's how fiddle make it:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){
var el = document.getElementById('whats-this-category');
el.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
    alert('event fired');
});
}//]]> 
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="" id="whats-this-category"><sub>Whats this?</sub></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think that was because javascript is before the html tag 'a', so it has to wait until all the document loads, and after add an event for an existing object.